# Unescape an escaped string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like

```
 rule = ".radio-inline,\n.checkbox-inline {\n  display: inline-block;\n}"
```

The string contains special characters like `\n`. How can I return the part of the string before `{}`?
For the above string it should return `".radio-inline,\n.checkbox-inline "`
I tried to write it using

```
Regexp.escape(rule).match(/(.*){/)[1]
```

The problem is that it returns:

```
"\\.radio\\-inline,\\n\\.checkbox\\-inline\\ \\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
rule = ".radio-inline,\n.checkbox-inline {\n  display: inline-block;\n}"

rule[/.*(?={)/m]
  #=> ".radio-inline,\n.checkbox-inline "
```

- `.*` matches zero or more characters from the beginning of the line. Being greedy by default, it matches as many characters as it can.
- `(?={)`, a positive lookahead, requires the character `{` to immediately follow the matched string, but it is not part of the match.
- `m` stipulates that the match is to be made over multiple lines.
- This uses the form of the method [String#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) that takes a regex as an argument.

Comment: If `.*` is greedy by default, how it matches only `"\\.radio\\-inline,\\n\\.checkbox\\-inline\\ \\"` in my example? Shouldn't it match the whole string?

Comment: You don't want to escape the string. Your regex works with a small change: `rule[/(.*){/m,1]`.

Comment: Consider `s = "abcabcabc"`. Then `s[/.*b/] => "abcabcab"`, but if we add the non-greedy quantifier, `?`, we get `s[/.*?b/] => "ab"`. Understand?

Comment: Yes, you've helped me quite a lot today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This regex gets you the part befor `{}`:

```
[^"{}]+(?={.*})
```

Try this [demo](http://regexr.com/39seg)

However it doesn't select you the `"` at the and and beggining, I hope this will work for you